# How to include dependencies jar using JNLP file?

Tags: java, maven, jar, java-web-start

Okay this is my first time to try Java web start, so I have jar that built with Maven as dependencies repository, and put it into Apache root folder including all dependencies jars inside folder lib, then I created key store, HTML, and JNLP file.

I started the Apache services, and tried to access localhost and it's ran smoothly until I ran jnlp file with my browser's java plugin, and `NoClassDefFoundError` showed, I knew that my dependencies jars aren't included. So I found [How to include jar dependencies in java webstart project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15376139/how-to-include-jar-dependencies-in-java-webstart-project) the accepted answer doesn't work for me, and I don't know what am I doing wrong?

Here's my JNLP file:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jnlp spec="1.0+"    codebase="http://localhost/transactionSimulator2"    href="launch.jnlp">

<information>
    <title> Transaction Simulator</title>
    <vendor> Daksa </vendor>
    <homepage href=""></homepage>
    <description>Transaction Simulator </description>
    <description kind="short">Transaction Simulator</description>
    <offline-allowed/>
</information>
<security>
    <all-permissions/>
</security>
<resources>
    <j2se version="1.6+"/>
    <jar href="TransactionSimulator-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar" main="true" download="eager"/>
    <target name="signLibs">
        <signjar destDir="lib"  alias="yusufNugraha" keystore="testKeys"
        storepass="yusufnugraha" force="true" >
            <path>
                <fileset dir="lib" includes="*.jar" />
            </path>
        </signjar>   
        <echo message="Library files were signed."/>
    </target>
</resources>
<application-desc main-class="com.daksa.transactionsimulator.ui.MainFrame">
</application-desc>
</jnlp>
```

Comment: What is `target` element doing in the `jnlp` file?  Check [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/deploymentInDepth/jnlpFileSyntax.html)  for the structure

Answer (score 4):

The correct way of including jar libraries is this:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jnlp spec="1.0+"    codebase="http://localhost/transactionSimulator2"    href="launch.jnlp">

<information>
    <title> Transaction Simulator</title>
    <vendor> Daksa </vendor>
    <homepage href=""></homepage>
    <description>Transaction Simulator </description>
    <description kind="short">Transaction Simulator</description>
    <offline-allowed/>
</information>
<security>
    <all-permissions/>
</security>
<resources>
    <j2se version="1.6+"/>
    <jar href="TransactionSimulator-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar" main="true" download="eager"/>
    <jar href="lib/file1.jar"/>
    <jar href="lib/file2.jar"/>
    <jar href="lib/file3.jar"/>
    <jar href="lib/file4.jar"/>
    <jar href="lib/file5.jar"/>
</resources>
<application-desc main-class="com.daksa.transactionsimulator.ui.MainFrame">
</application-desc>
```

Comment: it's acceptable until I have so many dependencies,  I mean it's not efficient, I have to add `<jar href="jar"/>` many times in jnlp, is there other options?

Comment: If you're concerned about the 'inefficiency' of writing all those lines for Jars, please spare a thought for *every client* that actually needs to **download those Jars!**

Comment: In Java webstart jnlp you cannot import jar files without specifying the exact filename and path for each jar file. You cannot have lib/*.jar for example. How many jar files do you have? You could write a script that generates the jnlp file by going through all files in a folder and adding them to jnlp one-by-one. As Andrea said, beware that if you have too many jar files it may be too slow for your clients to download them all.

Comment: This is not working, it gives error message as jar resources not signed by same certificate. This is obvious as third party jar will be signed by respective people

Comment: You will have to sign the jar file with your certificate for this to work.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an uberjar, where all libs are extracted into a larger jar file. In this case there is only file to deal with. The maven-dependency-plugin in Maven can do this for you. It fetched automatically all dependencies, so it's a great deal. I'm using this assembly file with the plugin:

```
    <assembly xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly/1.1.3"
          xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
          xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly/1.1.3 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/assembly-1.1.3.xsd">
    <id>jar-with-dependencies</id>
    <formats>
        <format>jar</format>
    </formats>
    <includeBaseDirectory>false</includeBaseDirectory>
    <dependencySets>
        <dependencySet>
            <outputDirectory>/</outputDirectory>
            <useProjectArtifact>true</useProjectArtifact>
            <unpack>true</unpack>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependencySet>
    </dependencySets>
</assembly>
```

You also have to sign the jar to be able to execute the application (in the browser).

**Note**: if you are using a crypto provider like Bouncy Castle, the signature of the crypto provider is broken when you are including this jar in the uberjar. In this case you have to add it as an additional jar as an `extension` in the `resources` element.

In the assembly file you have to exclude this then within the `dependencySet` element, e.g.:

```
<excludes>
    <exclude>org.bouncycastle:bcprov-jdk15on</exclude>
</excludes>
```

The extension JNLP would look like this:

```
<jnlp spec="1.0" href="bouncyCastle.jnlp">
    <information>
        <title>Bouncy Castle</title>
        <description>Bouncy Castle Crypto Provider</description>
    </information>
    <security>
        <all-permissions/>
    </security>
    <resources>
        <jar href="https://www.bouncycastle.org/download/bcprov-jdk15on-152.jar"/>
    </resources>
    <component-desc />
</jnlp>
```

You have to counter sign the jar in this case with the same key used for the main jar. Otherwise the extension is rejected. For some reason you have to use the same digest algorithm to get no verification error.